# fail2ban: how unban ip (using fail2ban-client)

Tags: linux

I using fail2ban v.0.8.2 but I can't unban an IP:

with fail2ban-client I see IP:

```
fail2ban-client status fail2ban

Status for the jail: fail2ban
|- filter
|  |- File list:    /var/log/fail2ban.log 
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  `- Total failed: 8
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 2
   |  `- IP list:   151.10.65.197 151.10.72.169 
   `- Total banned: 2
```

from man page should be sufficiently do:

```
fail2ban-client get fail2ban actionunban 151.10.65.197
```

output of command does not return error but:

```
iptables -L -nv |grep -b2 -a1 151

16262- pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
16351:    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       151.10.72.169        0.0.0.0/0           
16440:    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       151.10.65.197        0.0.0.0/0           
16529- 181K   48M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

and the output of

```
fail2ban-client status fail2ban
```

is same of above, hence command does not run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `fail2ban-client get jail-name actionunban ipaddress` That will allow you to unban an IP address. Use `iptables -L -n` to find the status of the correct jail-name to use?. The command you are giving: `fail2ban-client get fail2ban actionunban xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is correct given your output. Check status again to make sure it has not already been unblocked by the timeout. That would explain why the command fails.

Here is a good page [**Fail2ban Manual Unban Single Host (for iptables)**](http://highsecurity.blogspot.com/2010/11/fail2ban-unban-single-host-for-iptables.html) There have been changes to the unban procedure syntax (get/set) depending on version.

Comment: David: your command in reply it's the same of my question and does not run. Thanks for help.

Comment: Here there's a howto that explain the problem: http://blog.shanghai-hosting.com/2013/10/tech-how-to-unban-an-ip-address-from-your-server-using-fail2ban/ but "unbanip" in my version is not implemented (and I can't upgrade it)

Comment: @PolHallen did you use your specific <jail-name> with the actionunban command? Updated answer.

Comment: David: same problem. Either iptables -L -nv or fail2ban-client status fail2ban, IP is banned.

Comment: Hmm, What is the 'jail' name in which the ip is shown when you do `iptables -L -n`?

Comment: but using: fail2ban-client get fail2ban-default actionunban 151.10.65.197
Sorry but the jail 'fail2ban-default' does not exist

Comment: It looks like a naming issue. There have been changes in the syntax between the version in 0.8x timeframe. I'm still looking for you too. What headings [names] are shown in your jail.conf? Also, try 'set' instead of 'get'

Comment: The manual shows: `get "JAIL" action "ACT" actionunban` gets the unban command for the action "ACT" for "JAIL", so if you get the correct default "JAIL" name to supply from jail.conf it should provide the correct command to unban the IP. (It is probably unblocked anyway now as the timeout is bound to have expired)

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is to make sure you are issuing the command as `root` or with `sudo`, otherwise, attempting to change iptables will fail due to insufficient permission.

Comment: Thanks for help David, I investigate about it.

Comment: Your interpretation of `actionunban` seems to be wrong, see http://serverfault.com/a/349669/25852